# adding computed column in destination table from temporary table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure in which the data is populated into the destination table using a temporary table(in this i perform all the computation).
the problem i am facing is i have two columns which are getting its value by concatenating two other columns.
i.e.

```
concat(status_code|status_reason) as STATUS
concat(prior_status_code|prior_status_reason) as PRIOR_STATUS
```

Now this concatenation i have done it in temporary table.
i have to load its data into a destination table and the destination table doesn't have the columns STATUS and PRIOR_STATUS.
for loading the data i am using

```
insert into Destination( column_names,Status,prior_status)

select (column_names) from temporary table
```

so when i execute this part it throws me an error that columns are invalid as not present in the table.

P.S. I have used alter command to add those two columns in the destination. Still not getting the desired result.

Is there  any other way to do this and where am i going wrong in this?
 please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? You've tagged both...

Answer (score 0):

try this to add you field. it is important that you put the fieldnames in Backquotes. status is a reserved word.

```
ALTER TABLE youTable
ADD COLUMN `status` VARCHAR(100),
ADD COLUMN `PRIOR_STATUS` VARCHAR(100);
```

you can also specify the position of the field in the table like:

```
ALTER TABLE youTable
ADD COLUMN `status` VARCHAR(100) AFTER fieldxx,
ADD COLUMN `PRIOR_STATUS` VARCHAR(100) BEFORE fieldzz;
```

Comment: Is this for MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh - its for mysql